# Java project does not recognize latest code change in library dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I have a java project(Project A) that consumes a library(Project B) dependency as a jar. After making changes to the library project(Project B), rebuilding the classes, and replacing the lib jar file, when I debug, the debugger breaks at irregular points in eclipse. The latest change is not executed. I am running the project on tomcat. If I try to hot code after adding Project B in debug configurations, it says out of synch. Debugger in both java and class file behave in the same irregular way.
However, in eclipse de-compiler, the changes are reflected properly in the class where I made the change. I have also confirmed the library path in Project and External dependencies under Project A. FYI, I am just adding the following code

```
String key1 = "one";
String key2 = "two";
LOGGER.info("key1:" + key1);
```

There is no other code change and there is no error in the logs as well.
While doing a ctrl+shift+i  on key1 it says "Unable to resolve key2 to a variable".
There is no other copy of Project B jar where it might be referring to, since I have cleared all the cache.

Comment: Hard to say when an IDE is in between. Did you deploy and restart tomcat ? Is the lib provided or in the war ?

Comment: Yes, I always deploy and restart. The changes also reflect in the class file of the library under Project and External Dependencies of Project A. Lib is provided

Comment: *How* are you replacing the lib jar file? Is Eclipse aware that it's been changed? How is Tomcat being launched?

Comment: I am manually replacing the jar. Yes eclipse is aware since changes in class file are reflected in eclipse decompiler. I am using catalina jpda run command to launch.

Comment: What is this "eclipse decompiler" you're mentioning? Eclipse doesn't come with a decompiler.

Comment: I have downloaded a de-compiler to debug in class file in eclipse. When I open the class file, latest changes are present. However the breakpoint does not break on the latest change.